# Question about field extentions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) $ can be looked at as the field of rational numbers with $\sqrt{3}$ appended to it, and can be furthermore looked at like $\mathbb{Q}[x]/x^2 - 3$ what does a field extention look like in terms of something like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$

Would it be the quotient ring of another quotient ring? What do the coefficients look like? Is this field extension isomorphic to the complex numbers? I see i included, which I have never really seen before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer "concretely" what $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$ "looks like", we can do the following:

First of all, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}) = [\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})](i\sqrt{3})$, so we can form our ultimate field in two stages:

At the first stage, we get (real) numbers of the form: $a + b\sqrt{5}: a,b \in \Bbb Q$. As a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, this has the basis: $\{1,\sqrt{5}\}$, as you can see by noting that $a + b\sqrt{5}$ is nothing more than a $\Bbb Q$-linear combination of this basis.

Now $\{1,i\sqrt{3}\}$ is a $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$-linearly independent set (can you prove this?) which spans $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})](i\sqrt{3}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$, so $\{1,i\sqrt{3}\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ (We could also show, alternatively, that $x^2 + 3$ has no root in $\Bbb R$, much less in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$, which is contained in the reals, so that $x^2 + 3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$). Perhaps you have seen that for extension fields $F \leq K \leq E$, that:

$[E:F] = [E:K]\cdot[K:F]$, which in our case means that:

$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}):\Bbb Q] = 2\cdot 2 = 4$.

It turns out that $\{1,\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3},i\sqrt{15}\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$ over $\Bbb Q$, so that a "typical element" of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$ looks like:

$a + b\sqrt{5} + ci\sqrt{3} + di\sqrt{15}: a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q$.

It is not that hard to show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{5} + i\sqrt{3}) = \Bbb Q(\alpha)$, clearly $\alpha \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$, so that $\Bbb Q(\alpha) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$. For the reverse inclusion, note that:

$\alpha^3 + 4\alpha = (\sqrt{5} + i\sqrt{3})^3 + 4(\sqrt{5} + i\sqrt{3})$

$= 5\sqrt{5} + 15i\sqrt{3} - 9\sqrt{5} - 3i\sqrt{3} + 4\sqrt{5} + 4i\sqrt{3}$

$=16i\sqrt{3}$, which is thus in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, and therefore, so is $i\sqrt{3}$, since $\frac{1}{16}$ is rational. It then follows that $\sqrt{5} = \alpha - i\sqrt{3}$ is likewise in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, so $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}) \subseteq \Bbb Q(\alpha)$.

Finding the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ isn't too hard a chore, we know we should be looking for a monic rational polynomial of degree $4$. Now $\alpha^4 = -56 + 8i\sqrt{15}$, and $\alpha^2 = 2 + 2i\sqrt{15}$, so:

$\alpha^4 - 4\alpha^2 = -64$, that is: $\alpha$ is a root of:

$x^4 - 4x^2 + 64$, which must be the minimal polynomial since it is of minimal degree and is monic. We can conclude, then, that:

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}) \cong \Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^4 - 4x^2 + 64\rangle$, and its elements can be also written in the form:

$a + b(\sqrt{5} + i\sqrt{3}) + c(2 + 2i\sqrt{15}) + d(-4\sqrt{5} + 12i\sqrt{3}): a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q$, that is, as $a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2 + d\alpha^3$.

Comment: It seems like a really good answer. Using this and some other supplementary materials, I THINK, I  might finally understand this now

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3})$ is the same as first adjoining $\sqrt{5}$, then $i\sqrt{3}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ (or in the other order). So yes you could see it as
$$(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-5))[y]/(y^2+3)$$
or as
$$(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+3))[y]/(y^2-5)$$
Alternatively, by the primitive element theorem, there is some algebraic number $\theta$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. Finding the $\theta$ can sometimes be a bit tricky, but in this case you can prove that setting $\theta = \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{-3}$ works, and thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\theta) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ (necessarily degree 4 and irreducible).

To see that $\mathbb{Q}(\theta) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3})$, you can note that the former extension is galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, with galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, generated by the automorphisms sending $\sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{-3}\mapsto -\sqrt{-3}$. It's easy to compute that the galois group acts freely on $\theta = \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{-3}$, and thus the galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3})$. On the other hand, the galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, and thus all subextensions are galois, thus $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ equals its galois closure which is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3})$.

Alternatively you can prove this by explicitly writing $\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-3}$ as polynomials in $\theta$, but that seems difficult and less enlightening.

Comment: What would the coefficients look like in this field? Are they all the complex numbers? Or is it only the field of rationals with just those two extra elements. How do you envision this field?

Comment: What do you mean by "coefficents"? There is a imbedding $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, so you can think of that extension field as a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user121615 What field are you talking about? In general for some algebraic number $\alpha$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ can be thought of in a number of ways. Firstly, it's elements can all be written as polynomials in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Alternatively, it is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$. If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is degree $n$, then every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ can be written as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$

Comment: @user121615 ... to see that $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ is a basis, note that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ being $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ means that $\alpha^n + a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1\alpha + a_0 = 0$, which in particular means that $\alpha^n = -a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} - \cdots - a_1\alpha - a_0$, so powers of $\alpha$ higher than the $(n-1)$th power can be written as linear combinations of lower powers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, with a perfect base field (every finite extension is separable), any finite field extension is generated by one element, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(5),i\sqrt(3))=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ for a suitable $x\in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and you have $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f)$ for the minimal polynomial of $x$.